# Drop ceiling in a bathroom

Tags: ceiling, moisture

I'm thinking of installing a drop ceiling with acoustical tiles in a basement bathroom.
Will this be a problem with moisture even with an exhaust fan installed?

Answer (score 2):

This should not be a problem. While a drop ceiling is not as well sealed as a typical drywall ceiling, as long as the panels are in place it is good enough. There are many varieties available. While most should be fine with moisture, you may want to look at vinyl or other materials that specifically mention waterproof/water resistant capabilities.